# System.IO.FileNotFoundException been thrown when calling method in PCL in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library, class-library

I am working on decryption of a string (read from database) in PCL for Windows Phone 8 project. Below is the scenerio:

A solution having 3 projects, **Windows phone UI**, **windows phone portable class library** and **class library**.

Class Library Project is having a class **StringDecryption** which contains below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DecryptString
{
    public class StringDecryption
    {
        public string Decryption(string encryptedTExt)
        {
            var protectedText = this.ReadEncryptedData(encryptedTExt);

            // Decrypt the text by using the Unprotect method.
            var textByte = ProtectedData.Unprotect(protectedText, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

            // Convert the text from byte to string and display it in the text box.
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(textByte, 0, textByte.Length);

        }

        public byte[] ReadEncryptedData(string text)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(text).BaseStream;
            var textArray = new byte[reader.Length];

            reader.Read(textArray, 0, textArray.Length);
            reader.Close();

            return textArray;
        }

        public string Getname()
        {
            return "MyName";
        }
    }
}
```

I am referencing the dll from this class library to Portable class library and when calling method Decryption from this library it is throwing **System.IO.FileNotFoundException** but same is running fine when I am calling **Getname** method. Full message from exception is Could not load file or assembly **'System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Is there Any way to resolve this issue or any other way to encrypt or decrypt a string in PCL??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are referencing the "Class Library" from a "Portable Class Library".  This is not supported- the class library only supports one platform (probably the full .NET Framework) so it won't run on the other platforms your Portable Class Library targets.

> Is there Any way to resolve this issue or any other way to encrypt or
>   decrypt a string in PCL??

I'd recommend looking at the [PCL Crypto](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pclcrypto) library.

For some more general information that I think would help you, see my blog post: [How to Make Portable Class Libraries Work for You](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx)

Comment: One of those methods (Getname) in Class Library is being called successfully and others are not. It seems this is supported and It is having some other issue which I have to figure out.

I would like to try on PCL Crypto but I am not getting much information on that. Can you please provide me more information on how to use PCL Crypto Library?

Comment: @PraveshPesswani It's not supported.  You're just getting lucky with the Getname method because it is simple and doesn't call any other APIs.  PCL Crypto is an open source project.  I linked you to the NuGet package page, if you click on the "Project Site" link it will take you to the project page: https://pclcrypto.codeplex.com/  If you need more help with it I suggest posting another question on StackOverflow and possibly pinging Andrew Arnott (the author) on Twitter to point him to the question.